# Asyntask parallel run error in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

i have some code inside an android service, a timer that run some Asyntasks in every 3 seconds. but sometimes i get this error:

```
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at Dic.proj.pkg.notifService$check_last_asyn.doInBackground(notifService.java:251)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at Dic.proj.pkg.notifService$check_last_asyn.doInBackground(notifService.java:1)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-21 08:56:48.928: E/AndroidRuntime(26870):    ... 4 more
```

i dont know why. but i have a guess. my service starts from main activity by this code:

```
  Intent service = new Intent(DictionaryActivity.this, notifService.class);
  DictionaryActivity.this.startService(service);
```

i guess first time i start my service by opening main activity. then second time when im going to main activity, service starts again and my Asyntasks runs parallel and this cause this error...

is there any way to check if service started already, then don't start it again? how i can solve my problem?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` -- one of your members isn't assigned. Step through `doInBackgound` to find which one, or just double-click on the logcat entry.

Comment: post your doInBackground code..